# Ember.js: Adding item to an ArrayController without creating it first?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have been told time and time again to "never use `.create()` on a controller/ObjectController because Ember will do it for [me]".  I am confused as to how I then can add an item to an ArrayController without first creating it.

In my case, I am using a Controller (not an ObjectController) as an itemController for an ArrayController since it is not backed by AJAX-loaded data (...is this the correct usage?).  I would like to add an instance of my itemController to the ArrayController, but I can't figure out how to do that without first creating the item to be added.

JSBin here:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/momikuto/17/edit

TL;DR: I don't know how to add a Post object to the ArrayController without the `.create()` in the `addPost` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Models vs Controllers

I think the primary confusion here is between models and controllers.  A controller can [decorate a model](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/) to add display attributes but isn't the primary data object.

A model can be a simple JSON object, or it could be full-blown ember-data.

So, yes Ember will create your controllers for you.  And you specify the model(s) for the controller somehow (see below).

### Setting Controller Data

So in your example you are trying to seed your controller with two static posts id:1, id:2.  This is probably best [done in the Route](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/) as opposed to the View.